# htaccess rewrite help needed

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was trying to write a rewrite rule, but so far couldn't achieve what I want.
my site is in a subdirectory and the htaccess file is in that directory.

What I want is, if I go to `http://example.com/site/` or `http://example.com/site/index.php`it should rewrite to

```
http://example.com/site/index.php?key=2
```

The value of `key` won't change. It is fixed. I want it to load by default but hide from the url.

What I tried is,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php?key=2&$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

it's not working.
but if I go to address `http://example.com/site/anything` then it works.

Can you please help me in this?
I don't understand htaccess very well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ index.php?key=2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?key=2&$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I made a typo in my code sample, fixed now.
your code is working perfectly.
Thanks a lot.